# Regarding a trivial lemma

Tags: integration

Consider the following lemma:

If $\alpha(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and $\eta(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function satisfying $\eta(a)=\eta(b)=0$ then if,
$$\int^{a}_{b} \alpha(x)\eta(x)=0$$ for all $\eta(x)$ in $[a,b]$
it implies that $\alpha=0$  always.

Its proof uses just the fact that $\alpha (x)$ is continuous as shown below:

Proof:

Let $\alpha(x)>0$ for some $x=z$ in $[a,b]$ then since $\alpha(x)$ is continuous we can find a neighborhood of $z$ such that $\alpha(x)>0$ for $x$ being in this neighborhood $(z_1,z_2)$.

Now taking $$\eta=(x-z_1)^2(x-z_2)^2$$ for $x$ in this neighborhood and zero otherwise,

We find    $$\int^{a}_{b} \alpha(x)\eta(x) >0$$ which is a contradiction and hence the proof.

Now, I don't see why the continuity condition of $\alpha $ required for this lemma since when I saw this lemma it looked fairly obviously true to me independent of whether $\alpha $ is continuous or not.

Can someone give an example of a case where this lemma fails when we take $\alpha$ as not continuous so that it becomes clear to me why the continuity of
$\alpha$ is necessary for this lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\alpha(0)=1$ and $\alpha(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,1]$, then $\int_{0}^{1}\alpha(x)\eta(x)dx=0$.

Comment: Yes, this exactly helps. Just one more thing. Graphically, I was imagining a delta function initially for $alpha$ which wasn't working since area under the graph is 1 for delta. Here it works, since alpha shoots up-to to 1 at a point without any width thus including no area under it. Is this graphical interpretation of your answer correct?

Comment: I think I understood what you said. Yes, that almost was what I thought. Or equivalently, just put $\alpha$ to be the zero function, but then that would be continuous. To make it discontinuous, perturb some points. Note that the integral remains the same with finitely many perturbation of points.